# Debugging Monomac apps built using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, monodevelop, pdb-files, monomac

Does Monodevelop allow .net assemblies to be debugged that have been built using Visual Studio (i.e. assemblies that have .pdb symbols rather than .mdb symbols)?

If so, how are source files located during source level debugging?

This would be very useful to allow common assemblies to be built on Windows and used on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1, you can convert *.pdb files to .mdb files,

Step 2, you can use mdb to debug your process,

http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Debugger